# ubuntu trusty (14.04LTS): how do I update package libemail-sender-perl from v1.300010 to v1.300011 (needed for bugzilla 5.0.2)

Tags: perl, ubuntu, apt-get, bugzilla

When you want to run Bugzilla 5.0.2 on ubuntu trusty (14.04LTS) you need libemail-sender-perl v1.300011.

But when you do:
apt-get update && apt-get install -y libemail-sender-perl you only get v1.300010.

How can I install the newer version?

Comment: I think this is better suited for https://askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cpanminus` to upgrade the module (you might need to install `make` and `gcc` first):

```
apt-get install cpanminus
cpanm Email::Sender
```